# Array output from matlab c s-function

Tags: c, matlab

I have been writing an c s-function block for simulink.I want my output as an array

```
//
FILE *datafile;      
datafile = fopen("datafile.dat","r");
pwork[0] =  datafile;


//


//
static void mdlOutputs(SimStruct *S, int_T tid)
{
    real_T       *y = ssGetOutputPortSignal(S,0);
    real_T *a;
    real_T *b;
    real_T *c;
    void** pwork = ssGetPWork(S);
    fscanf(pwork[0],"%f %f %f",y[0],y[1],y[2]);

}
//
```

But it doesn't work like that.I guess the problem is with allocating y[1] and y[2]..

Comment: I think what you want is [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/) if you want to copy the elements to an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about Matlab, but I do know that the arguments to a `scanf` call should be *pointers*, and unless `real_T` is typedefed as a pointer already it will not work.

Besides, you are using `fscanf` which is for reading from a `FILE` pointer.

I don't know if this will work or not, by try this instead:

```
sscanf(pwork[0], "%f %f %f", &y[0], &y[1], &y[2]);
```

Comment: Actually it is a file pointer.I am sorry that i didnt mention it   'FILE *datafile;
      
      datafile = fopen("datafile.dat","r");
      pwork[0] =  datafile;'